# Solspace Importer: Native EE Grid and Relationships

Tags: solspace, relationships, grid, solspace-importer

Does Solspace Importer support the native EE Grid and Relationship fieldtypes when importing into channel entries?

I may have made a mistake to assume compatibility to include those native fieldtypes when purchasing, but I've missed some pretty obvious stuff in my day before!

I have a set of XML files that is used to update just under 1000 entries in an EE 2.9.2 site, but the current add-on being used doesn't support cron imports in batches. I was hoping to replace it with Importer, but haven't had luck with it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, Importer does not support importing into Grid fields, nor does it support creating/populating relationship fields. Have you looked at [DataGrab](http://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/datagrab)?

Solspace does have a 30 day money back guarantee.

Comment: DataGrab is the one I am using, but it cannot import with batches via cron. Looks like this may be the 3rd Solspace addon that I will be adding features or bugfixing in the near future. I just hope the work I am submitting to them can be used to help others with the features I have been after.